# Rx subject is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In this Namespace I export a Rx subject of type string:

```
namespace something.TaskHandling {

  export const taskSelected$ = new Rx.Subject<String>();
```

In my `TaskListComponent` class that is in the `something.TaskHandling.Overview` namespace I have:

```
public clickListItem() {
  taskSelected$.onNext('responsive-view-filters');
}
```

And in my `ResponsiveNavigationComponent` in the `something.CustomerService` namespace I import the subject:

```
import taskSelected$ = something.TaskHandling.taskSelected$;
```

I initiate the stream in my `OnInit`:

```
public $onInit() {
    this.observeTaskUpdates();
}

private observeTaskUpdates(): void {
    taskSelected$
        .filter(classValue => !!classValue)
        .subscribe(classValue => {
            this.toggleView(classValue);
        });
}
```

This code compiles with no issue and when I `go to definition` on the `taskSelected` I end up at the exported `taskSelected$` subject.

But when I run the app I get this in my ResponsiveNavigationComponent.ts:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

So the `taskSelected$` is not defined in my `ResponsiveNavigationComponent` class. What am I missing?

Comment: Could your files be loading in the wrong order?  `import taskSelected$ = something.TaskHandling.taskSelected$;` basically translates to `var taskSelected$ = something.TaskHandling.taskSelected$;` and is executed at the time it is reached.

Comment: Hmm that could be it since it looks like I can load it in another component. Going to check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a order issue, I had to hard reference the actual file where the `taskSelected$` const was initiated > `/// <reference path="../TaskHandling/module.ts"/>`. Not sure if this is a solution to a underlying issue.